# d3v4 - Chord Chart refactor and enhancements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I'm playing around with different types of infographics -- I had this idea of a chord diagram - like a ball of yarn -- where you may have 2 sets of data -- like Skills and Experience opposite ends of a circle -- and then using "strings"/lines - to mark which set of skills a person has against their level of experience -- where the strings/lines merge towards the bottom of the chart -- maybe to show a photo of the person etc..

I've recently upgraded this from d3v3 to v4.

//version 4
https://jsfiddle.net/7mjfa3bp/

I am interested in cleaning up this code base -- and maybe adding some animation to it -- if it be the dougnut chart aspects tween first -- then the lines draw one by one? I am open to interesting evolutions/enhancements for this chart -- if giving it more aspects will serve a person -- like Skills, Experience, Work Place --

In this sample to get the groups to separate out - I had to manipulate the input data to add GAPS - and then remove the influence for plotting labels and pointers.

```
            var id = 0;
            var d = [];

            var totalDataSpread = 0;
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
              totalDataSpread += value.set.length;
            });

            console.log("totalDataSpread", totalDataSpread);

            $.each(data, function(index, value) {

              var segmentTotal = value.set.length;
              $.each(value.set, function(i, v) {
                d.push({
                  group: value.group,
                  label: v,
                  id: id++,
                  value: 1 // ((segmentTotal/totalDataSpread)*10) 
                });
              });

              var gapSize = 10;
              if (segmentTotal > 10) {
                gapSize = 20;
              }

              //console.log("create GAP", value.set);
              d.push({
                group: "gap",
                label: "gap " + id,
                id: -1,
                value: gapSize
              });

            });



            data = d;
```

- notes

Is there a more streamlined approach in this refactor - like mapping or something I've missed in the architecture of the chart. -- Should I use a pie chart base where I faked the "gaps" -- or really work around creating arcs that repel each other to the poles? Then maybe not have the "gap" arcs appearing so it looks more like two opposing arcs

Comment: I think this part is your question.. "I am open to interesting evolutions/enhancements for this chart..." in which case this is just too broad and you're really just inviting discussion. Try narrowing down to something more specific that you're having difficulty with.

Comment: I think what I am trying to say -- is how to improve the code base -- I had to add a gap block for example - and then remove it.

Comment: I'm sure that would be a good discussion but not what stackoverflow is for. Take a look at this and I think you'll see what I mean. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok - but what I've currently done - is there a more streamlined approach -- like mapping or something I've missed in the architecture of the chart. -- Should I use a pie chart base -- or really work around creating arcs that repel each other to the poles?